# Quantity count issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having an issue in quantity count for an e-commerce app.  When one product is added to cart, the cart shows "product", when another of the same product is added, then it shows "1 product". So, 2=1. I'm new to ruby, obviously. How to include a proper count when quantity > 1?

```
def add_product(product_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.increment(:quantity)
  else
    current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
  end
  current_item
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the code you are using in order to try to count the number of items?

Comment: @JustinWood, To know the number of line items, you can look at `current_item.quantity`. `quantity` is just an attribute of `LineItem`. For this to work, it needs to be initialised, incremented and decremented correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when you start with your first item, `quantity` is `nil`. You'd have to set it to `1`. Something like this should work:

```
current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, quantity: 1)
```

So, your method would look like this:

```
def add_product(product_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.increment(:quantity)
  else
    current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, quantity: 1)
  end
  current_item
end
```

By the way, you could use [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-initialize-by) to shorten your code to one line:

```
def add_product(product_id)
  line_items.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: product_id).increment(:quantity)
end
```

Comment: Please provide feedback with your down vote. Thank you.

Comment: Downvote was not from me, your solution worked.  Thank you @Mischa.

Comment: @alex I added a suggestion for improving your code somewhat.